# How to view the last user that accessed a folder in the terminal?

Tags: command-line

Is there a command to give me the last user that accessed a specific folder in Ubuntu?

It is like auditing the folder for security reasons .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**auditd**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/auditd/). To install it, run the following command from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install auditd
```

#### How do I set a watch on a folder for auditing?

```
sudo auditctl -w /path/to/folder -p rwx -k password-file
```

The above command monitoring `/path/to/folder` for anyone that may perform a write, read or execute operation on that folder.

#### How do I find out who changed or accessed a folder?

Use `ausearch` command as follows:

```
sudo ausearch -f /path/to/folder -i | less
```

More about: [Linux audit files to see who made changes to a file](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html).